# How do i get GMT time in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, gmt

I know it's a repeating a question , but i didn't get solution from those answer's . please can anybody tell me , How do I get GMT in ios , if the device time is wrong also .

Thanks in advance

Comment: [NSDate date] returns time in GMT

Comment: @George , if my device is 2 hours late , then still i get correct time ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615833/objective-c-setting-nsdate-to-current-utc

Comment: @George i tested above link code , but when i change my system time then utc time also changing .

Comment: @riyaz: If the device *time* is wrong (and not the time zone) then there is nothing you can you (apart from contacting an NTP server).

Comment: @MartinR i tried that also . but i am getting some issue from that .. please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845981/ios-ntp-framework-sync-issue

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";
NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",timeStamp);
```

Comment: thanks for response , i tried this code but no luck . if we change device time then timestamp value is changing according to that .

Comment: @RIYAZ i am also getting same problem. do you find any solution for this one?

Comment: @HariBabu No , i also tried with ntp-ios but no luck .

Comment: Guys consider to force the user set the accurate time after setting up the application, save this value somewhere maybe NSUserDefaults, I am afraid there is no way to accomplish what you want from client side without connecting a webserves or remote time service.

Answer (score 0):

You must rely on an external server to achieve this. There is no built in method other than the ones for recovering the local phones time.

Here is a github project where they try to do exactly this for iOS :
https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp

Comment: i tried that , but i am getting some issue with that ,please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845981/ios-ntp-framework-sync-issue